# getting syntax error while putting ternary expression inside a string interpolation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
<Image source={require(`../assets/${expand[0] ? 'expand':'expandDown'}.png`)} />
```

expand[0] is true or false

I am only getting syntax error. what is wrong here . Since we are inside {} we should be able to use JS correct ??

Comment: There is no syntax error here, and if there was, you should tell us what the actual error is

Comment: don't require dynamic strings, it makes it impossible for something like a bundle to determine what it needs to replace this with (You're creating an app, just require your assets up front, and then pick the right one as source here). Also, have your requires at the top of your file, so you only require things once, instead of what you're doing here, rerunning requiring every time this Image gets created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable for the image source:

```
const imageSource = expand[0] ? require('../assets/expand.png') : require('../assets/expandDown.png')
<Image source={imageSource} />
```